# I want to make a circle with buttons in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react native project and I want to create a circle shape with the buttons.

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAOeU.png)

There is a central button and the other buttons must shape a circle like in the picture.

Comment: Can you please provide more info like you want to create circular button or want to place multiple buttons inside circle? can you please share some image sample like you want like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZuSt.png check it out

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with what you have already tried and the errors you encountered while doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final result:

[image]

Here is how you can do it:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
  const handleClick = (num) => {
    alert(`${num} clicked`);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
      <View style={styles.btnContainerMiddle}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(1)}
          style={[
            styles.button,
            { position: 'absolute', left: -100, top: 50 },
          ]}>
          <Text>1</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(2)}
          style={[styles.button]}>
          <Text>2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(3)}
          style={[styles.button, { position: 'absolute', left: 100, top: 50 }]}>
          <Text>3</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.btnContainerMiddle, { justifyContent: 'center' }]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(4)}
          style={[
            styles.button,
            { height: 100, width: 100, borderRadius: 50, margin: 10 },
          ]}>
          <Text>4</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.btnContainerMiddle}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(5)}
          style={[
            styles.button,
            { position: 'absolute', left: -100, bottom: 60 },
          ]}>
          <Text>5</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(6)}
          style={[styles.button]}>
          <Text>6</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => handleClick(7)}
          style={[
            styles.button,
            { position: 'absolute', right: -100, bottom: 60 },
          ]}>
          <Text>7</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  btnContainer: {
    // flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    padding: 8,
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    borderRadius: 100,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  btnContainerMiddle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    margin: 10,
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 35,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

Here is [Live Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/circular-btn-example) of the app, you can play around with it to make further adjustments.

Comment: You are welcome, an next time do post the accompanying source code so that fellow programmers could help you better :) Happy coding.

Comment: I'm a beginner at react-native and also inexperienced with front-end development, so there was actually no source code. I just basically did not know how to code it. Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code of creating rounded button

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  style={{ borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center',
    width:100,
    height:100,
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    borderRadius:100,
  }}
  >
  <Icon name={"chevron-right"}
    size={30}
    color="#01a699" />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TouchableOpacity to create custom buttons. Heres and example

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={{borderColor:"red",width:50,backgroundColor:"red",borderRadius:100}}
    onPress={onPress}
  >
    <Text>Press Here</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

You can tune the width and borderRadius to get a proper circle